# Matching whitespace in bash

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I want to delete duplicate files made by itunes, which all end in " 1.mp3". I've come close to matching but I don't know how to match the space. Can somebody writeup a command to recursively delete those files from the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go through your iTunes collection and remove Nickelback's *If I care 1.mp3* but, only if the Nickelback original MP3, *If I care.mp3*, still exist. Right?

Hey, your musical tastes are up to you...

This should do the trick:

```
find -name "* 1.mp3" | while read file
do
   if [ -e "${file% 1.mp3}.mp3" ]
   then
       rm $file
   fi
done
```

I am finding all the duplicates (songs that end in space-1.mp3) and piping them to the `while` statement.

The `${word%filter}` syntax says take the `$word` and remove from the right hand side the glob expression `filter`. Thus, `${file% 1.mp3}` is the name of the file sans the `1.mp3` suffix. Now, `If I care 1.mp3` becomes `If I care`. We, therefore need to add the `.mp3` suffix back on. Thus `${file% 1.mp3}.mp3`. This gives us the original name of the file.

Now, we use `-e` test to check if that file exists. If it does, we can delete the space-1.mp3 version of the song.

I ran some basic tests, but I suggest you try it out first (maybe change `rm $file` to `echo Removing file $file` first and verifying that those files do have the original).

Comment: My apologies for replying so late, It worked perfectly, and thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for `find`!

```
find . -type f -name '* 1.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other solutions, but checks that the file *without* the " 1" suffix really exists, so it does not accidentaly remove songs whose names end in " 1".

```sh
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*' '1.mp3 ; do
    if [[ -f "${file% 1.mp3}.mp3" ]] ; then
        rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: there's a loophole here when the `file.mp3` is actually a symlink to `file 1.mp3`. Besides, you could do a checksum to see whether the files are really the same... oops you could do a fuzzy check in case the encoding/tags were different. Getting rather sidetracked now

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "* 1.mp3" -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster:

```
find . -name "* 1.mp3" -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '* 1.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

which kbyrd mentions is the best way according to me because of the -print0 and -0 combination because.

> -print0
>                 True; print the full file name on the standard output,  followed
>                 by  a  null  character  (instead  of  the newline character that
>                 -print uses).  This allows file names that contain  newlines  or
>                 other  types  of white space to be correctly interpreted by pro‐
>                 grams that process the find output.  This option corresponds  to
>                 the -0 option of xargs.